# How To Do Paging In MVC DOT NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I Have A Module That Shows All Records From Backhend But The Problem Is Record Is Too Much Like It Shows 22k Records On Screen And Screen Gonna Sluggish And All Components Working Slow So I Have To Do Paging In MVC.

**Controller**

```
    public string TrafficMovement(string formData)
    {
        try
        {
            formData = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(formData);
            ReportsAC _obj = new ReportsAC();
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            ReportsMapper mapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportsMapper>(formData);
            UserSession userSession = (UserSession)Session["userSession"];

            mapper.Company_Id = userSession.Company_Id;

            dataset = _obj.TrafficMovementAC(mapper);


            return "{\"Status\":true , \"Message\":\"success\" ,\"Data\": " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataset) + "}";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return "{\"Status\":false , \"Message\":\"" + ex.Message.ToString() + "\"}";
        }
    }
```

**jQuery**

function Traffic_Movement() {

```
try {

    var url = "/Reports/TrafficMovement";
    var dataString = {};
    ShowLoader();
    //dataString.Report_Period = $("#Report_Period").val();

    dataString.tfMonth = $("#tffMonth").val();
    dataString.tfYear = $("#tffYear").val();

    AjaxSubmission(dataString, url, $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()).done(function (data) {

        if (data.Message == "success") {

            var strHTML = '';
            var strVAL = '';



            if (("#tfbdy") != undefined) {
                $('#count_data').html("TOTAL RECORDS: " + data.Data.Table.length);
               // $("#trBody").html("<tr><td colspan='15'></td></tr>");

            }

            if (data.Data.Table != undefined && data.Data.Table.length > 0) {


                for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.Table.length; i++) {


                   //here i m doing binding work
                }

                $("#tfbdy").html(strHTML);

      }


                 }



                       HideLoader();


 }).fail(function (result) {
        //console.log(result.Message);
        HideLoader();
    });

} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    HideLoader();
}

    }
```

**Component**

```
public DataSet TrafficMovementAC(ReportsMapper mapper)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlParameter[] sqlParameter = new SqlParameter[6];
            sqlParameter[0] = new SqlParameter("@Company_Id", mapper.Company_Id);
            sqlParameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@Branch_Id", mapper.Branch_Id);
            sqlParameter[2] = new SqlParameter("@User_Id", mapper.User_Id);
            sqlParameter[3] = new SqlParameter("@FY_ID", mapper.FY_Id);
            //sqlParameter[4] = new SqlParameter("@Report_Period", mapper.Report_Period );
            sqlParameter[4] = new SqlParameter("@tfMonth", mapper.tfMonth);
            sqlParameter[5] = new SqlParameter("@tfYear", mapper.tfYear);


            dataAccess.ExecuteSelectQueryWithDataSet("SKYBOOKS_TRAFFIC_MOVEMENT_LIST", sqlParameter, out dataSet);
            return dataSet;
        }

        catch
        {
            throw;
        }



    }
```

If Someone Suggest me Paging Idea Then It Will Means A lot, Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter of pageNo and pageSize to your controller method. Cache the whole data fetched initially if not expected to be changed.
Then in each request, increment thr pageNo and return only the corresponding page.

Pseudo Code

StartIndex = (pageNo x page Count) 
Data = from StartIndex, StartIndex + pageCount
        Return dt.rows